# How to clear exception mask in ifstream?

Tags: c++, io

I set the exception mask `failbit` of an ifstream by doing:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main() 
{
    try {
        std::ifstream in("in.txt");
        in.exceptions(std::ifstream::failbit);
    } catch (std::ios_base::failure &fail) {
        // handle exception here
    }
}
```

Is there any way I can clear or restore the exception mask?

Answer (score 3):

Found the solution:

```
std::ifstream::iostate old_state = in.exceptions ();
```

will save the old exception mask.