# C++ set "blank" or reset exception mask of ifstrean (ios)

Tags: c++, ifstream, bitmask, c++-ios

Is there a way to reset the exception mask of an [`ios`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/) object to a "default" value?
(Is it defined by the standard?)
I was originally interested in `ifstream`, I got to `ios` tracing the inheritance of `ifstream`.

I found a workaround [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36922577/2707864), but this depends on having stored the original state of the mask for the object in a variable, and this may not be available.

Comment: The usual way to do so, is to save the old state as done with the workaround you linked. The default is to have an exception mask with none of the bits set, thus `0` casted to `std::ios_base::iostate` (`std::ios_base::iostate{}` respectively) should do what you want.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ "The default is to have an exception mask with none of the bits set" - do you have a reference for that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`exceptions`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/exceptions) member functions is inherited from `ios`. It is a [`std::ios_base::iostate`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/iostate) which has 3 possible bits to be set: `badbit`, `failbit` and `eofbit`. The "default state" is `std::ios_base::goodbit` (0). So just `my_ifstream.exceptions(0)` will reset it (`my_ifstream.exceptions(std::ios::goodbit)` will also work and be more clear).

Comment: I guess the second option would be preferred, for clarity. Moreover, it would be implementation-independent (I don't know if the standard specifies `0` for `std::ios_base::goodbit`; I am using `ios_base` since it is more fundamental).

Comment: "The "default state" is `std::ios_base::goodbit` (0)." Would love to see a reference for this.

Comment: @bers Here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/init